# Ubuntu 11.10 RVM Installation Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, rvm

On a fresh Rackspace instance, I try installing RVM with this:

```
bash -s stable < <(curl -s https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer)
```

Then it gives me this error:
-sh: Syntax error: redirection unexpected

I've seen fixes with "source ~/.bash_profile", but that gives me another error "-sh: source: not found"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you do it the intuitive way:

```
wget https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer
chmod +x ./rvm-installer
bash ./rvm-installer
```